# Is there a way to make a single bar chart that tracks color based on date in Google Sheets or Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I've attached an image that's the best way to describe it. As the date increases from left to right, a different color for that range is displayed. [image]

Some sample data:

```
Date    Temperature
Week 1  Cold
Week 2  Cold
Week 3  Cold
Week 4  Cold
Week 5  Cold
Week 6  Cold
Week 7  Cold
Week 8  Cold
Week 9  Cold
Week 10 Cold
Week 11 Cold
Week 12 Cold
Week 13 Cold
Week 14 Cold
Week 15 Cold
Week 16 Cold
Week 17 Cold
Week 18 Cold
Week 19 Cold
Week 20 Cold
Week 21 Cold
Week 22 Cold
Week 23 Cold
Week 24 Cold
Week 25 Nice
Week 26 Hot
Week 27 Hot
Week 28 Hot
Week 29 Hot
Week 30 Hot
Week 31 Hot
Week 32 Hot
Week 33 Hot
Week 34 Hot
Week 35 Hot
Week 36 Hot
Week 37 Hot
Week 38 Hot
Week 39 Hot
Week 40 Nice
Week 41 Cold
Week 42 Cold
Week 43 Cold
Week 44 Cold
Week 45 Cold
Week 46 Cold
Week 47 Cold
Week 48 Cold
Week 49 Cold
Week 50 Cold
Week 51 Cold
Week 52 Cold
```

Comment: Sends to be achievable with a horizontal stacked bar chart.  Please post some sample data and we try to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to calculate date instead of week number, I've used this formula:
  `=DATE(2016,1,1)+(B2-1)*7`,
  you may have other definition for it, but I think it fits for purpose,
  after inserting it, also change it's format: home - number format - custom: `mmm`
- next, insert a pivot chart (in Excel 2013: insert - pivot chart)
- Select columns:

  - legend (series): temperature
  - axis (categories): date
  - values: temperature (Excel will automatically use "count of temperature", it's fine for us)
- Excel probably will automatically create a bar chart, if not, change it to bar chart
- right click on a column - format data series - series options - set "series overlap" to 100% and "gap width" to 0%
- right click on the horizontal axis, and select format axis

  - in "number" check "linked to source"
  - in "labels" - "specify interval unit" - enter one which is appropriate (I can't say universal value here, in my example it's 15)
- right click on vertical axis - format axis

  - min: 0, max 1
  - tick marks major & minor: none
  - label position: none

[image]